# Python - Creating a script that takes full-page screenshots of all links within a webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, operating-system

Been stuck on this problem for a while. I'm basically trying to create an archive of a website by opening links with a specific x-path element (in this example, "/html/body/div[1]/span[1]/a[20]" and taking a full-page screenshot, then saving the screenshot to a folder I've created.

I'd prefer if possible to use FireFox but if not possible because of CloudFlare, then Microsoft Edge.

My output is a huge mess of error codes. I'd really appreciate some help with my logic, as I'm still quite new to programming.

Thank you.

```
import os, bs4, requests, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options as EdgeOptions


# create folder for storage
os.makedirs('archive', exist_ok=True)

url = ''


def archiver(url):

    # retrieve webdriver
    options = EdgeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='C:path\to\msedgedriver.exe', options=options)

    # open url
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()

    while not url.endswith('//'):

        # open boards that end with "/"
        try:
            # open and get page name
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//html//body//div[1]//span[1]//a[20]")).click()
            page = driver.current_url
            page_name = str(page)

            # wait for the page to load
            time.sleep(5)
            # print "downloading" string
            print('Updating archive of ' + page_name + '.')

            # create screenshot of a page and file name
            driver.save_full_screenshot(page_name + ".png")
            # save file to folder
            save_screenshot = open(os.path.join('archive', os.path.basename(page_name)), 'wb')

        except:
            print('None found')
            # close the browser
            driver.quit()

    # print "done" string
    print('Updated.')


archiver(url)
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`.screenshot`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/screenshot-element-method-selenium-python/) method? like `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//body").screenshot(f'{page_name}.png')` or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a full screenshot by setting the window size to be equal to `full page width` x `full page height`. You can do this only in headless mode

```
full_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
full_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
driver.set_window_size(full_width, full_height)
driver.save_screenshot(path)
```